# How to create a WCF REST/JSON service in IIS without svc file?

Tags: ajax, wcf, .net-4.0

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885100.aspx) (MSDN) says in the first step:

> Alternatively, you can also use configuration to add an AJAX endpoint.

I'm unable to access my service endpoint following their example exactly. (VS2010, .NET 4.0, Win7) I always come back with 404-not found when I try to access it.

Comment: Are you certain you're using Factory=System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory in your svc service file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [404 when running .net 4 WCF service on IIS (no svc file)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793127/404-when-running-net-4-wcf-service-on-iis-no-svc-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the *endpoint* using configuration, but you need the .svc file to host the file in IIS.

If you really don't want an .svc file, you can also use the the ASP.NET Routes integration (more info in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/25/using-routes-to-compose-wcf-webhttp-services.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662952(VS.100).aspx) - in that case you'll specify the factory when you're setting up your route.