# Configure multiple WCF bindings or services in one config

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest, wcf

I am trying to use multiple services in one web.config. The issue I am having is that when I go to https://localhost/APGame.WebHost/PlayService.svc/checktraining?g=3 I get The resource cannot be found error (404). I have tried doing this using one service and multiple service contracts and that did not work either.

I can visit https://localhost/APGame.WebHost/PlayService.svc so the service is running. I am just unsure what i am doing wrong.

**Web.config for WCF**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="json">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="APGame.Services.GameManager">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="APGame.Contracts.IGameService" />
      </service>
      <service name="APGame.Services.PlayManager">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="json" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="APGame.Contracts.IPlayService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding transactionFlow="true" sendTimeout="00:20:00">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add service="APGame.Services.GameManager" relativeAddress="GameService.svc" />
        <add service="APGame.Services.PlayManager" relativeAddress="PlayService.svc" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Service Contract**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPlayService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/checktraining?g={groupGameId}")]
    bool? CheckTraining(int groupGameId);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to get results using SoapUI?

Comment: You don't have a "APGame.Contracts.IGameService" contract.

Comment: @granadaCoder I do have a contract for IGameService and that works perfectly fine. I am trying to create a new service or new service contract to work as a RESTful service for ajax w/ AngularJS

Comment: @EricS I have never worked with SoapUI is this something I should use?

Comment: Yes, its a very handle tool for testing web services. It has a lot of features. If you just need to serve data, SoapUI can confirm your service is up and running.

Comment: I will check it out. Shouldn't I be able to test by visiting the method URI?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I don't think you can view a JSON data return in a browser. I recently built my first JSON service and had the same issue but it works fine in SoapUI.

Comment: You can't just randomly add a service without a backing contract (that actually exists).  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint.contract(v=vs.110).aspx    You can create multiple endpoints.......but in your example .. all of your endpoints must refer to the IPlayService contract (because that one actually exists)

Comment: The IGameService contract also exists I just did not post the code for it here as it is not the service with the issue

Comment: You have two different contracts under one service.  Try separating the config into two separate `<service>` sections, one for each unique contract.

Comment: @Tim isn't that how it currently is? `<service name="APGame.Services.GameManager">` and `<service name="APGame.Services.PlayManager">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried so many different solutions (such as this one: [404 when running .net 4 WCF service on IIS (no svc file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793127/404-when-running-net-4-wcf-service-on-iis-no-svc-file)) and none of them worked.

I realized that the issue was that it was being accessed through HTTPS. Even though I could access the `.svc` file (https://localhost/APGame.WebHost/PlayService.svc), I could not access any methods after that (such as: /Playservice.svc/json/2). In order to fix this, I added the following to my web.config inside the `<bindings>` tag

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

I then added `bindingConfiguration="webBinding"` to my service's endpoint